# ArrayList in class

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of my custom class and for each of those I would like to each keep their own arraylist of computers. Here is my code for the class:

```
class Services {
    public String name;
    public String path;
    public ArrayList<String> computers = new ArrayList<>();

    public Services(String name, String path, String computer) {
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.computers.add(computer);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public void addComputer(String computerName) {
        this.computers.add(computerName);
    }

}
```

In my main method I am checking my arraylist of Service for an object with the same name and if it exist then I just want to add that to the arraylist for that object.

However, this is not working and it seems I am just ending up with just one arraylist of all computers not specific to each object of Service.

Here is the section of my main method that uses this class.

```
stream.iterator().forEachRemaining(x -> {
    try {
        final boolean[] nextLine = {false};
        lines(x.toAbsolutePath(), Charset.forName("UTF-16")).forEach(y -> {
            if (!nextLine[0]) {
                // Finding Separator
                if (y.contains("-----------")) {

                    //Letting the program know the next line is a service.
                    nextLine[0] = true;
                }
            } else {
                //Splitting the service name from the path.
                String[] service = y.split(" + ");
                final boolean[] exists = {false};
                String computerName = x.getFileName().toString().substring(0, x.getFileName().toString().length() - 4);

                allServices.iterator().forEachRemaining(z -> {

                    if (z.name.contains(service[0])) {
                        exists[0] = true;
                    }
                });
                if (!exists[0]) {

                    //Creating new service object if it does not exisit. 
                    //Params are Service name, service path, computer name
                    Services serviceToAdd = new Services(service[0], service[1], computerName);
                    //Then adding it to the list to be printed out later. 
                    allServices.add(serviceToAdd);
                } else {
                    //Service name already exists, just adding the computer name to its list of affected computers. 
                    allServices.iterator().forEachRemaining(z -> {
                        if (z.name.contains(service[0])) {

                            if (!z.computers.contains(computerName)) {
                                z.addComputer(computerName);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
                );
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
});
```

Ultimately, I am trying to compile a list of services. With that list of services I need to know the name of the service, the path, and which computers have them. I am getting the computer name from the name of the file. It appears that the list of computers for each service is the same list instead of a different list for each service. How do I fix this? Do I need to make a list of lists? That seems redundant and ill performing.

Comment: Can you please add the method you talk about (main?). Where you add to an `ArrayList` of Services?

Comment: Can you please explain more what you are trying to do, and what is going wrong? If you could boil down the code to the smallest possible amount that still demonstrates the error, that'd be helpful

Comment: thanks for the additional explanation. I'll take a look

Comment: The hardcoded 0's trouble me. I'm not really following your logic, but I wouldn't expect you to for example check that `z.name.contains(services[0])`. So you only ever add a computer name if while iterating thru all services, the current service matches the name of the first service? Seems odd right there.

Comment: I am using `String[] service = y.split( + );` to create that array. [0] is always the name of the service and [1] is always the path of the service.

Comment: After performing more tests I have confirmed that the list it is adding all the computers to is the same list.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty hard to tell you what you are missing as you do not provide us the `main` method which is the most important one relating to your post.

So, with the few info I had, here a little algorithm that would loop over all your stored computers according to the code you posted. That should help you figure out what you are missing, else please post the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String newComputer = "UberPC3000x";
    boolean alreadyExistSomeWhere = false;
    for (int i = 0; !alreadyExistSomeWhere && i < allMyServices.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; !alreadyExistSomeWhere && j < allMyServices.get(i).computers.size(); j++) {
            alreadyExistSomeWhere = allMyServices.get(i).computers.get(j).equals(newComputer);
        }
    }

    if (!alreadyExistSomeWhere) //Then it means it was not found and you are free to add wherever you want.
    {

    }
}
```